Grabar audios para sitio web en sistemas iOS
tengo un código javascript y HTML 5 para hacer grabaciones de voz en sitios web.
Consiste en grabar la voz, después se puede reproducir, eliminar y agregar a una lista (como una vista previa), si un audio se agrega a la lista se puede reproducir ese audio o eliminar.
Mi problema es en navegadores móviles iOS que al grabar un segundo audio no se escucha ni en la vista previa ni en la lista, pero en sistemas android si se escuchan todos los audios que grabo tanto en la vista previa como en la lista
¿Cómo puedo solucionar el problema para iOS?
Muchas gracias
    <button id="startButton">Iniciar Grabación</button>
    <button id="stopButton">Detener Grabación</button>
    <button id="playButton">Reproducir Audio</button>
    <button id="saveButton">Guardar Audio</button>
    <button id="deleteCurrentButton">Eliminar Audio Actual</button>
    <ul id="audioList"></ul>
    <audio id="audioElement" controls style="display: none"></audio>

Este es mi código javaScript en donde selecciono los botones para interactuar con ellos.
Utilizando las APIs mediaRecorder y getUserMedia para las notas de voz, usando blobs para guardar la URL del audio
// Seleccionar elementos del DOM
const startButton = document.getElementById('startButton');
const stopButton = document.getElementById('stopButton');
const playButton = document.getElementById('playButton');
const saveButton = document.getElementById('saveButton');
const deleteCurrentButton = document.getElementById('deleteCurrentButton');
const audioElement = document.getElementById('audioElement');
const audioList = document.getElementById('audioList');

let mediaRecorder; // Variable para almacenar el objeto MediaRecorder
let chunks = []; // Array para almacenar los fragmentos de audio grabados
let recordings = []; // Array para almacenar los URLs de los audios grabados

// Función para iniciar la grabación
function startRecording() {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
        .then(function(stream) {
            mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);

            mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(e) {
                chunks.push(e.data);
            };

            mediaRecorder.onstop = function() {
                const blob = new Blob(chunks, { 'type' : 'audio/mp3' });
                chunks = [];
                const audioURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                recordings.push({ url: audioURL, blob: blob }); // Guardar el URL y el blob en el array de grabaciones
                audioElement.src = audioURL;
            };

            mediaRecorder.start();
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log('Error al acceder al micrófono: ' + err);
        });
}

// Función para detener la grabación
function stopRecording() {
    mediaRecorder.stop();
}

// Función para reproducir el audio en audioElement
function playAudio(audioURL) {
    audioElement.src = audioURL;
    audioElement.play();
}

// Función para guardar el audio grabado en el array y mostrar en la lista
function saveAudio() {
    if (audioElement.src) {
        const url = audioElement.src; // Obtener el URL del audio actual en audioElement
        const blob = recordings[recordings.length - 1].blob; // Obtener el blob del último audio grabado
        const listItem = document.createElement('li');

        const audioPlayer = document.createElement('audio');
        audioPlayer.src = url;
        audioPlayer.controls = true;
        audioPlayer.style.display = "none";

        const playButton = document.createElement('button');
        playButton.textContent = 'Reproducir';
        playButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
            playAudio(url);
        });

        const deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
        deleteButton.textContent = 'Eliminar';
        deleteButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
            const index = recordings.findIndex(rec => rec.url === url);
            if (index !== -1) {
                recordings.splice(index, 1);
                audioList.removeChild(listItem);
            }
        });

        listItem.appendChild(audioPlayer);
        listItem.appendChild(playButton);
        listItem.appendChild(deleteButton);
        audioList.appendChild(listItem);
    }
}

// Event listeners para los botones
startButton.addEventListener('click', startRecording);
stopButton.addEventListener('click', stopRecording);
playButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (audioElement.src) {
        audioElement.play();
    }
});
saveButton.addEventListener('click', saveAudio);
deleteCurrentButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    audioElement.src = ''; // Detener la reproducción si está reproduciéndose
});
```


yo creo que puede estar asociado a como safari maneja los MediaRecorder , has intentado liberar recursos de los Blob URLs anteriores y Reasignar el objeto MediaRecorder?

Los productos de Apple son caros, y como poca gente los usa (los que pueden darse el "lujo" de comprarlos), es difícil que venga gente que sepa del tema, nunca tuve dinero para comprar cosas de Apple, pero tampoco lo haría, y tal vez por esto es que la calidad del sistema es peor, porque no hay retroalimentacion de la gente. Si tu objetivo de reproducir un audio fue resuelto en Android, ¿Entonces para que usar ios? ¿Se puede escuchar otros audios del sistema o solo es en el navegador? Pero si es para que lo escuche gente que solo tiene IOS me parece mas razonable.
